# What is the relationship between Xml and Html?

Tags: html, xml

I want to ask you about web design

What is the relationship between Xml and Html?

Comment: @MichaelKa, no need to be so harsh. It's an interesting, abstract and technical question. Good thing someone answered it already, but other than that, it's a good question.

Comment: A good question for StackOverflow can be answered in two or three paragraphs. I don't think anyone should be asking questions that (a) require an essay-length answer, and (b) are answered in any basic introductory text book. This kind of question tends to attract low quality answers (as can be seen from the 5 attempts to answer it, none of which is much good). In retrospect, I should probably have voted to close it as out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

HTML and XML are both descendants of an earlier markup language called SGML (Standard Generalized Markup Language).   SGML is a complicated set of rules that define document structures.

XML is a subset of SGML that does the same thing, using fewer rules.  Since XML is a less-complicated derivative of SGML, XML is more easily implemented on large networks such as the Internet.  The primary role of XML is to define data.

Check this for more info: [Link](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-html-and-xml)

Comment: The link leads to a really crappy online learning resource failing even to mention SGML as the superset and origin of both HTML and XHTML/XML.

Answer (score -1):

in XML we define own Tag for example `<name> raj </name> <city> Delhi </>`

in HTML it has inbuilt Tag for example `<h1> Header </h2>`

Comment: For the record, this is wrong: in both cases, you'd need to follow a predefined schema (ie, a blueprint of what you're allowed to use). And, in both cases, more than one schema can be used.

Answer (score -1):

xml and html are both markup languages this is a similarity between them.

Comment: for structuring we it can used 

HTML is a markup language itself.       - XML provides a framework to define markup languages.